# How to get the Next months results from date field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a date.
I need to get all results for the upcoming month.

*******Sample Code I have but it returns 2 months of data**********

---

```
where worktype = 'mpm' and status = 'active' 
and (nextdate >= DATEADD(MONTH,01,GETDATE()))
and (nextdate < DATEADD(MONTH,02,GETDATE()))
```

Some Data:

```
2016-01-27 00:00:00.000
2016-01-28 00:00:00.000
2016-02-02 00:00:00.000
2016-02-02 00:00:00.000
```

It is returning 2 months of data.

Comment: Try to change your operatots to `>` and `<=`

Answer (score 0):

Your results are returning *exactly* what you've requested.  You're requesting to get anything within the date range of `One Month from Today` and `Two Months from Today`.

All of your results are within that range.

If you are only interested in the data that is within the next calendar month (at the time of writing, `January 2016`), this would suit you better:

```
Where  worktype = 'mpm' 
And    status = 'active' 
And    nextdate Between 
           DateAdd(Month, -1, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GetDate()) +2, 0))
    And    DateAdd(Day, -1, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GetDate()) +2, 0))
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can also use the following:

```
Where  worktype = 'mpm' 
And    status = 'active' 
And    nextdate Between 
           DateAdd(Day, 1, EOMonth(Current_Timestamp))
    And    EOMonth(DateAdd(Day, 1, EOMonth(Current_Timestamp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
 WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, nextdate) = DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE()))
```